# How to put post featured image inside a div in genesis?

Tags: php, css, html, wordpress, genesis

I am having a slight problem with using the genesis framework. My goal is that every post featured image be in a div with the same class. I want to be able to apply a background image to the outer div so that when a user hover over the div, the opacity of the featured image goes to 0 and display a play button behind it (which will be an image), kind of like this website does with its posts:

[Inside Personal Growth](http://insidepersonalgrowth.com/)

[image]

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: The image above is currently what I have. It is a post and the image is displayed using the <img> tag which is kind of messing me up. I want the <img> tag to be inside of a div.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want. You want the `<img>` to be inside of the `<div>`? Why don't you just place it there? It would really help if you gave us some code.

Comment: Let me clarify that this is a wordpress site...and adding html content isn't exactly the easiest thing in the world to do. The image above is a wordpress post using the genesis framework. I am trying to put the featured post image inside of a div. But, not having a lot of background in wordpress I do not know how to.

Answer (score 1):

U want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zL4m7/1/) ?

```
img{opacity:0.5}
```